# Run Teamcity builds through command line

Tags: command-line, teamcity

I want to run a build job created in Teamcity through command line. Is it possible to run teamcity builds through command line? If yes, then what is the command for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `curl` is an option you can try this http request:

```
curl http://<user name>:<user password>@<server address>/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=<build configuration Id>
```

[Have a look](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way to trigger build via command line is using REST API.

```
curl -u user:password --request POST  http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/buildQueue --header "Content-Type:application/xml" --data-binary @build.xml
```

build.xml example:

```
<build>
  <buildType id="HelloWorld_A"/>
    <lastChanges>
      <change id="760"/>
    </lastChanges>
</build>
```

For more details see the related [section](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild) in the documentation.